# How to import variables from multiple modules in one line?

Tags: python, import

```
from module_1 import *

from module_2 import *
```

Is there a way that I can group the two statements above in one line?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I recommend taking a look at [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/2745495)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, however you can do:

```
import module_1, module_2
```

Which will import both `module_1` and `module_2`.

This will make the code more self-documented as well, as in, for example you'll have to use `module_1.method()`, but it's up to you.

You may also want to read this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/187471) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

No other way than using a semicolon:

```
from module_1 import *; from module_2 import *
```

But this is a very pointless thing and you should never do this.

Comment: you may want to add a comment, that you shouldnt do that nevertheless